Download Samsung Off-Screen Memos
I'm using a Samsung Note 20 and one of my most used features is the screen off memo. I take several handwritten notes every day. I want to convert the notes to text, categorize the text by hashtags I generally add within the notes, and file the notes into another app that I use to track todos and ideas, etc. What is the best method to grab all notes off the phone?
I'm open to all the approaches:

Pushing to Samsung cloud
Using any third-party app
Mounting the phone on my laptop
Building my own note sync Android service


I would start by identifying the app that provides the off-screen memo functionality. You need the app packageName (the internal non-localized app identifier) of the app. Using this you can search the internet what other people write about exporting and so on. Or if you have some development experience you could extract the app from the device, decompile it and check what interfaces (activity, services, ..) it provides.
